# Recover hermitian matrices out of the knowledge of their trace

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $M_{1},\ldots, M_{m}$  be $m$ hermitian $N\times N$ matrices, and $tr=\frac{1}{N}Tr$   the normalised trace on the algebras of such matrices.  If you know the quantities  $tr(M_{i_{1}}\ldots M_{i_{k}})$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $i_{1},\ldots ,i_{k}\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, can you find the matrices $M_{i}$?

The problem comes from article " Probabilités libres et matrices aléatoires" of Philippe Biane:

"Si l’on considère plusieurs matrices $M_{1},\ldots, M_{m}$, la donnée du spectre de chacune d’elles ne suffit pas à déterminer leurs positions relatives dans l’espace de toutes les matrices hermitiennes. Néanmoins, une construction classique dans la théorie des algèbres d’opérateurs, la construction de Gelfand-Naimark-Segal (GNS) montre que si l’on connaît les nombres $tr(M_{i_{1}}\ldots M_{i_{k}}) $ où $k$ parcourt les entiers positifs et les indices $i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}$ prennent des valeurs arbitraires dans $\{1,\ldots, m\}$, alors on peut retrouver les matrices $M_{i}$ à une conjugaison unitaire globale près $M_{i}\mapsto UM_{i}U^{\ast}$ (c’est-à-dire que $U$ ne dépend pas de $i$). Il est facile de voir que la connaissance de ces nombres permet de retrouver le spectre de n’importe quel polynôme en les matrices $M_{1}, \ldots, M_{m}$."

Now if I try to translate it into English, we have:

"If we consider several matrices $M_{1},\ldots, M_{m}$, the data of the spectrum of each of them is not sufficient to determine their relative positions in the space of all Hermitian matrices. However, a classical construction in the operator algebra theory, the construction of Gelfand-Naimark-Segal (GNS) shows that if we know the numbers $tr(M_{i_{1}}\ldots M_{i_{k}}) $  where $k$ traverses the positive integers and the indices $i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}$ take arbitrary values in $\{1,\ldots, m\}$, then the matrices $M_{i}$ can be found up to  a global unit conjugation $M_{i}\mapsto UM_{i}U^{\ast}$  (that is, $U $does not depend on $i$) . It is easy to see that the knowledge of these numbers makes it possible to find the spectrum of any polynomial in the matrices $M_{1}, \ldots, M_{m}$."

Comment: suppose $m=1$, how would go about to reconstruct the $N\times N$ matrix $M_1$ if all you are given is the sum of its diagonal elements?

Comment: As @CarloBeenakker's comment indicates, I'm not sure that you have asked the question you intended to ask. Were you thinking of the fact that one can recover the spectrum of a hermitian matrix by knowing the traces of sufficiently many powers?

Comment: I have voted to close this question until the OP clarifies what they meant to ask, and what cases they are thinking of (e.g. whether $m$ is much larger than $N$, or $m$ is fixed and we are taking a large $N$ limit)

Comment: Take the case where $m=2$, and suppose you know the traces of all words in $M_{1}$ and  $M_{2}$, $i.e.$ the products of type $X_{1}X_{2}\ldots X_{n}$ where  $X_{1}X_{2}\ldots X_{n}\in \{M_{1}, M_{2}\}$. My question is to know if it is possible to recover the matrices $M_{1}$ and  $M_{2}$  from these traces of all words in $M_{1}$ and  $M_{2}$.

Comment: $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n}\in\{M_{1}, M_{2}\}$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover them completely: if you simultaneously conjugate all matrices
by some invertible matrix, the traces will not change. But up to this conjugacy,
at lest for $SL(2)$ matrices, the traces determine the conjugacy class:
MR0314993
Horowitz, Robert D.
Characters of free groups represented in the two-dimensional special linear group. 
Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 25 (1972), 635–649,
without the condition that they are Hermitean.

Comment: Of course in SL(2) knowing the trace of a single matrix tells us its eigenvalues, so we are in a much more restricted setting than the one mentioned in the original question

Answer (score -2):

Such a question have been answered by C; procesis in his paper: ''The invariant theory of $n\times n$ matrices.,Advances in Math., 19(3): 306-381, 1976.''

Comment: This answer does not explain how/why Procesi's results answer the stated question